# How to change FROM name in Amazon SES with boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-ses

I'm trying to change the `from` name that appears in the email client using boto3. But I'm unable to do this.

This is my code:

```
client = boto3.client(
        'ses',
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        region_name='us-west-2'
    )

    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                to_address,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                    'Data': html_content,

                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                    'Data': 'Email formato text.',
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Data': subject,
            },
        },
        Source='no-reply@example.com.br',
    )
```

The `from` in client always comes as no-reply, how I change this to a custom name?

Answer (score 14):

Its pretty straightforward :)

```
Source='A Custom Name <no-reply@example.com.br>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you **have not verified** the email address.

The [boto3 documentation for `send_email()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email) says:

> **Source:** The email address that is sending the email. This email address must be either individually verified with Amazon SES, or from a domain that has been verified with Amazon SES. For information about verifying identities, see the [Amazon SES Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html).

Comment: I already verified the email address, because I can send emails with it.